# Heikin Ashi candles and real market

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

The script I created receives signals using heikin ashi candles, but when I look at the backtest results, the entries and exits to the positions are realized at the price shown in heikin ashi candles. This creates unrealistic results and it looks like the startup is making too much profit. I want this: My signals should be formed according to heikin ashi candles, but the levels included in the transactions should be taken according to the candlesticks on the real market. How can I do this?

I tried to create what I wanted with chatgpt, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your script on the standard chart but request data from the Heikin Ashi chart.

You can do that by using the `request.security()` function. In order to receive the Heikin Ashi values, you need to create a new ticker based on Heikin Ashi. You can do that with the `ticker.heikinashi()` function.

Here is an example:

```
ha_close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close)
```

Also, recently, Tradingview has introduced a feature so that you can force real price values to be used in order fills. You can also use that.

[image]

Comment: i created my strategy, but I couldn't see the fill orders standard OHLC option in the properties section. how can I solve the problem?

Comment: By the way, thank you very much for your response. Dec. When I do what you say, I get the following error: Could not find function or function reference 'ticker.heikinashi'.

Comment: What is your pinescript version?

Comment: That option in my screenshot is only available in `v5`. And if you are using `v4`, you should use `heikinashi()` instead of `ticker.heikinashi()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I update to v5, I can create orders with real market data in backtests.